# Forces on a wheel during braking (Quarter Vehicle Model)

Tags: mechanical-engineering, abs

I have created a simple xcos simulation for quarter wheel using the equations given at the bottom of the image.

I understand the total torque on the wheel will be the braking torque and the friction torque. My question was right till the end the friction torque is really high( I am calculating mu from Burckhardt tire model). Even as the velocity goes to zero, the friction force gets higher (mu*mg). Is this realistic? Will a tire right up to the point it actually stops experience such high torque?
Thanks!
[image]